# Fos Elastica remove common words(or, and etc..) from search query

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

Hello I`m trying to get query results using FosElasticaBundle with this query, I
can't find a working example for filtering common words like (and, or) if it is possible this words not to be highlighted also would be really good. My struggle so far :

```
    $searchForm = $this->createForm(SearchFormType::class, null);
    $searchForm->handleRequest($request);

    $matchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $matchQuery->setField('_all', $queryString);

    $searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
    $searchQuery->setQuery($matchQuery);
    $searchQuery->setHighlight(array(
        "fields" => array(
            "title" => new \stdClass(),
            "content" => new \stdClass()
        ),
        'pre_tags' => [
            '<strong>'
        ],
        'post_tags' => [
            '</strong>'
        ],
        'number_of_fragments' => [
            '0'
        ]
    ));
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want (and, or) to be ignored or not to have a value on your search?
If that's the case you may want to use stop words on your elasticsearch index.
Here's a reference.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html

Comment: Yeah, tried that, enabled stopwords in the config.. the only thing that this achieved was not highlighting the stopwords.

Comment: Nope. The foselasticabundle examples are kinda non existent, not completely sure how to use the objects they provide :/